# Why: error: implicit declaration of function 'sys_close'?

Tags: nvidia, system-calls

I am trying to install the latest NVIDIA driver in Debian 12; part of the process involves building some kernel modules. Most of these compile without error, but it fails near then end (around 96%, whatever that means). The log shows this error several times, here for `nv-caps.c`:

```
     CC [M]  /tmp/selfgz170986/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.125.06/kernel/nvidia/nv-caps.o
   /tmp/selfgz170986/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.125.06/kernel/nvidia/nv-caps.c: In function 'nv_cap_close_fd':
   /tmp/selfgz170986/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.125.06/kernel/nvidia/nv-caps.c:598:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'sys_close' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     598 |     sys_close(fd);
         |     ^~~~~~~~~
   cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Looking in `nv-caps.c`, I find:

```
/* sys_close() or __close_fd() */
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
```

And in `/usr/src/linux-source-6.1/include/linux/syscalls.h`:

```
...
asmlinkage long sys_close(unsigned int fd);
...
```

So, I can understand why it should fail at an implicit declaration of `sys_close()`, but I can't see why it doesn't pick up the quite explicit declaration in the header file, which is included. Any thoughts?